# How to launch flutter app using custom voice line

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to know if there's anyway to launch flutter app using a custom voice line, just like Google voice assistant launch when we say 'Ok Google'

Comment: What have you tried so far? A simple command like "open [insert your app name]" should do.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**App Actions** is used for letting users in order to launch specific features in your app using **Google Assistant**. You can check out more on this link: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-actions/overview

It is the tutorial to implement these actions on your flutter application: https://fidev.io/ok-google-flutter/